# google map obtain key error your input was invalid

Tags: android, google-maps, cmd

I want to get a google map key, so i have to get md5 , i get it like this

```
C:\Windows\system32>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin\keytool.exe" -list -al
ias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Users\User\.android\debug.keystore" -storepass
 android -keypass android
androiddebugkey, Apr 9, 2012, PrivateKeyEntry,
```

i got the answer, now i want to get the key from https://code.google.com/apis/console, i input md5 then ";" then the package name, so i got this error `your input was invalid`

why please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use SHA1 key for generating Map Key, which you can obtain using `-v`

`keytool.exe  -v -list .....`

Answer (score 0):

Divya is right in old version we used md5 key but in new google map api v2 we used SHA-1 key

this link is more usefull for getting key and integrate google map

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start

Answer (score 0):

According to the Google Maps Android API v2 documentation, You need to enter SHA-1 fingerprint along with the application's package name.